# Evaluate the Jacobian if $u = xy, v = y-x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The following equations are given:
$u=xy$ and $v = y - x$.
To evaluate the Jacobian, you have to express $x$ in terms of $u$ and $v$, and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.
However, I don't see how you would exactly do this.

I tried using the ABC formula as follows:
$$u = xy$$
$$x = \frac{u}{y}$$
$$x = \frac{u}{v+x}$$
$$x(v+x) = u$$
$$vx + x^2 = u$$
$$x^2 + vx - u = 0$$
$$x = \frac{-v \pm \sqrt{v^2+4u}}{2}$$
$$y = v + x = v - \frac{v \pm \sqrt{v^2+4u}}{2}$$

But then you have two equations for x and y? So can someone tell me if my method is incorrect and if yes, how you would do this with the correct method to evaluate the Jacobian?

Comment: You wanted x and y in terms of u and v, and you found them.  Just take your partial derivatives now and put together the Jacobian.

Comment: It is not necessary to do so. Please note that If both function $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable, then the Jacobian of $f$ is invertible. So you can find $J^{-1} = \frac{\partial (u, v)}{\partial (x, y)}$ and that gives you $J$.

Comment: @MathLover But you need to still get a formula in terms of $u,v$, in general. Sometimes things simplify magically in the double integral.

Comment: @TedShifrin of course but instead of finding $x, y$ in terms of $u, v$ and then differentiating, which is more cumbersome here, it is easier to find $J^{-1} = (x+y)$ in terms of $u, v$. But of course it depends on whether OP is allowed to do that yet or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two possible solutions because if $(x,y)$ is one solution for given $(u,v)$, then $(-y,-x)$ is another solution. That means that $(u,v)$ aren't good coordinates forr the whole plane, because they do not differentiate point $(x,y)$ and $(-y,-x)$. You can only use them on some subsets of a plane, for example with $x+y>0$.

If you have condition $x+y>0$ then from
$$ (x+y)^2 = (y-x)^2 +4xy = v^2+4u$$
you can conclude that
$$ x+y = + \sqrt{v^2+4u}$$
so $$ x= \frac{-v+ \sqrt{v^2+4u}}{2}$$
$$ y= \frac{v+ \sqrt{v^2+4u}}{2}$$
If you have $x+y<0$ then you use the other solutions:
$$ x+y = - \sqrt{v^2+4u}$$
$$ x= \frac{-v- \sqrt{v^2+4u}}{2}$$
$$ y= \frac{v- \sqrt{v^2+4u}}{2}$$
From this you can calculate the Jacobian.

Another way to calculate Jacobian is to calculate the inverse of the Jacobian first:
$$ J^{-1} = \frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)} = \left|\begin{array}{cc}y & x \\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right| = x+y$$
which means that
$$ J = \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} = \frac{1}{x+y} = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2+4u}}$$
where you need to choose the sign depending on whether $x+y>0$ or $x+y<0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I still dont quite understand yet why the sign depends on x + y > 0 or x + y < 0 ?

Comment: You have $(x+y)^2 = v^2+4u$ and when you take the square root you need to choose the correct sign.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier: if we denote by $\;J\;$ the Jacobian you need, then with inverse matrices we're done:

$$J:=J\frac{(x,y)}{(u,v)}=\left[J\frac{(u,v)}{(x,y)}\right]^{-1}=\begin{vmatrix}y&x\\-1&1\end{vmatrix}^{-1}=\frac1{x+y}$$

Comment: But the Jacobian should be in terms of u and v as well right, in order to evaluate the integral? So how would you find x+y in terms of u and v?

Comment: @Stallmp True, in this case the Jacobian is not a constant but something that depends on $\;x,y\;$ and thus thus the time and effort saving is not that big.